# De-encrypt a Minecraft packet sent from Minecraft server. Python. Problems with unknown packet length

Tags: python, encryption, minecraft

I have a Python program that logs into an online Minecraft server.
This includes getting set up with Azure and getting access with authentication with Microsoft.
Ect.

I got it to the point where I can send the login packets, generate the shared secret and authenticate with Microsoft and Mojang servers.

After sending the encryption response packet, I log into the Minecraft server successfully and then start receiving a packet. The problem is that Minecraft servers fully encrypt the packets INCLUDING the length of the packet. I'm not sure how to receive the entire packet so that I can decrypt it and parse it, since the length of the packet is also encrypted.

There are almost zero resources on the internet about this kind of thing so I'm really not sure where to start.

I'm using socket.recv(bytes) to receive different parts of the packet

To make things clear I'm not struggling with decrypting the packet, just receiving the entire thing when I don't know the length of it.

When the packet is unencrypted it as simple as

```
# Unpack a variable-length integer from a stream
def varint(s):
    # Initialize the value and read up to 5 bytes
    d = 0
    for i in range(5):
        l = get_bytes_from_stream(s, 1)

        b = ord(l) # Receive a single byte
        d |= (b & 0x7F) << 7*i # Shift and OR the byte into the value
        if not b & 0x80: # Check if the last bit is 0
            break
    return d

#unpack a packet
def packet(s):
    l = varint(s)
    id = varint(s)
    return (l, id)

log("Packet Info: ", unpacker.packet(s)) # Packet Info
```

The second value printed is the length in bytes of the rest of the packet, so I can just do

```
s.recv(length)
```

or something like that, but now the first varint is part of the encrypted packet.

Any help would be much appreciated and will also probably help any others who are on the same path as me.

Comment: I don't know what the max packet length is in this protocol, but if it's relatively short, the entire packet will usually be received in one `recv`call.  Yes, it's dangerous to assume that.  In that case, the best you can do is to keep accumulating data, and try to unpack it each time you get more data.

Comment: https://wiki.vg/Protocol is the wiki for the Minecraft protocol, each packet it sends varies greatly in length, and I can't lose any of the next packets' data.
The max length is 2097151 bytes but almost 100% of packets will be a lot smaller than this and most of the time there will be multiple packets received if I did that much.

Comment: How is the packet encrypted? Usually you don't need to wait for the full packet to start decryption. Either you decrypt a stream, or you have update/final methods to your disposal. If those are not present you can generally hack it together (e.g. CBC decryption of X blocks without padding).

Comment: The Minecraft protocol uses an AES/CFB8 stream cipher to encrypt the packets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any of those wondering the same thing I did, here is what I found.

Since Minecraft uses an AES/CFB8 stream cipher to encrypt the packets it means you just need to decrypt packets in 16-byte blocks as you receive them.

Create a cipher (I used pycryptodome library)

use the shared_secrete for the IV and the key

```
AES_encryption_cipher = AES.new(shared_secret, AES.MODE_CFB, iv=iv, segment_size=8)
```

To get the length of the packet, you just need to keep decrypting blocks of 16 bytes as you receive them. Once you have enough bytes in plain text to get the length variant, then wait again until you've decrypted enough bytes for the rest of the packet. Just make sure to save whatever leftover decrypted bytes you have after the last block (because they will be part of the next packet sent from the server).